# Lost My Minecraft Saves Folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

So being a mac user, it took me forever to find my minecraft saves folder. Because I do not want to need to find it again, I moved the folder to my desktop, instead of copying and pasting it or just leaving the folder alone. Now my saves do not appear, and I cannot save worlds. How do I find the folder and where did I put it (I also dragged the folder back into where I thought it should go and it just disappeared. Could someone advice me on what to do?

Answer (score 6):

You can't move the folder away from where Minecraft keeps it – Minecraft won't know where you put it and will just assume you've deleted your saves.

You need to put it back in your "minecraft folder" which is in `[home]/Library/Application Support/minecraft/`.

However, you probably can't find that location easily because Library is a hidden folder. The easiest way to find it then is to open Minecraft, log in, click **Options…** → **Resource Packs** → **Open resource packs folder**.  This will open a Finder window showing you a (probably empty) folder. With this Finder window at the front, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>. That will navigate up into your Minecraft folder. Put your saves folder here, so that there is the `minecraft` folder with a `saves` folder inside it, with your worlds inside that.

If you want to be able to find your saves easily still, right-click the saves folder and choose "alias". This will make a shortcut that you *can* move anywhere you want.

Comment: For reference: on Windows, the location is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft` where AppData is likewise hidden.

Comment: @TravisChristian True. This is a Mac-specific question, but I imagine other people might come here with the same trouble on Windows or Linux. (Fortunately for Linux users, it's much easier to find in `~/.minecraft`!)